# Can i post text data using fetch in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm using react js and I want to post text and return a text.

Can anyone help me in posting text and receiving text? I have used 
`content type text/plain` but that didn't help.

Is there any way to do?

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    },
    body: this.state.url
}

fetch("http://localhost:3000/messages", options)
    .then(response => response)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({
            code: data
        });
    });
```

This is what I have tried to get the text value from api

I am getting an error as

> Uncaught promise typeError failed to fetch

Comment: Post to where? Recieve from what? What do you want to do ?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: read about https://github.com/axios/axios to make api calls

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` returns a "promise" for a Response object which has promise creators for json, text, etc. depending on the content type. So the code should be changed to.

Also consider adding a catch block for the promise in case of errors and check the console output error (if any ).

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    },
    body: this.state.url
}

fetch("http://localhost:3000/messages", options)
    .then(response => response.json()) // or response.text()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({
            code: data
        });
    })
     .catch(err => { console.log('error while fetching', err) });
```